# Codeigniter, insert ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, insert

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I have to insert an ID in my table, but it doesn't work, I made this :

```
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: do you have the table configured to have a primary key that auto increments?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the value of $data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's fixed, I just forgot to use auto_increment in my ID column. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

this works normally for me:

```
 function insert($data){

        $this->db->insert('users',$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();

      }
```

you have to set your `ID` field to `AUTO INCREMENT` and be sure `$data is an associative array`, like:

```
$data = array(
     'db_field'=>'value'
);
```